# Bootstrap 3.0 responsive css for large element classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have all input and button elements to appear normal size for < 767px screens. If it is a > 767px screen though I need the .btn-lg and .input-lg classes be applied to all buttons and inputs. This allows for an easier touch experience on larger screens. How can this be done? Can it be done with purely CSS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
//all the styles for btns within 767px
}
@media screen and (min-width:767px){
//all styles above 767px
}
```

You can achieve this with jquery too:

```
if($(window).outerHeight(true) <  767){
   //add class to your btns and lists and remove classes...
}
```

This is one approach and there are many.

Comment: Using the media queries, I would just have to redefine the class myself for different sizes?

Comment: you can change the values of the property for the current classes using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done with purely CSS.

Please check the "Responsive utility classes"

here: [bootstrap scaffolding](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

Also you might need http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ - Media Queries

Comment: I've thought about that. I could make various html elements and just show and hide the appropriate ones. This is probably the cleanest solution.